# Queuing incoming API requests in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have a platform where users send continuously data to.
This data is sent by the Android App synchronously, as otherwise an incorrupt state can happen.

This incorrupt state still comes up, when an API-call fails (due to an exception in rails) and the consecutive API calls come through.

Therefore I would like to queue the incoming API requests per user if an error happens.

What is the best way to queue the incoming API requests?
1) Are gems like resque suitable for this requirement? And if yes, should each user get an own queue?
2) Or is it cleaner and simpler to build own queues in a new model in Rails?

Comment: you can use redis list for this with the name of the list uniq to each specified user and push data in queue and then operating on background either via resque or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a gem called [Event Machine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine).

It is a gem used for handling multiple requests in real time, with various configuration options and ability to scale, keeping high performance and stability.

[This](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) is another the gem's official site.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both answers.
I decided at the end to put build own queues per user,
and a worker of delayed_job will then continuously go through these queues.

To keep the iteration of a queue strictly synchronous, I use a locking mechanism at the queue.